# how can i make screen have multi screens like iOS or android multi tasking action flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
home: Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
drawer: SideBar(_changeIndexNumber),
appBar: AppBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
elevation: 0,
foregroundColor: Colors.white,
title: TextField(
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Footlight',
color: Colors.white,
backgroundColor: Colors.white),
decoration: InputDecoration(
border: UnderlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Search...'),
),
actions: [
Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 2),
child: Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),
)
],
),
body: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
child: Screens[screenIndex],
),
),
);
}
}

Comment: Hey ammar, I recommend you to format your code with the brackets { } available in the text editor, this way is would be readable and someone will be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this dart code written by someone in the community.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=33611484d7b78eb1b2b93d9fabc7d439